# Were do I add a PWA/TWA on my server

Tags: web-application

I am trying to add Progressive Web Apps to my server.  I would prefer not to create a new web site for each app.  My preference is is to add each app to a sub-directory off of a website like this:  www.example.com/app1

The problem is that when I run the Statement List Generator here:  https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

It only works if I place assetlinks.json here:  www.example.com.  And if that is the case then I can only have one app in www.example.com.  I have tried placing assetlinks.json here 1) www.example.com/app1  2) and www.example.com/app1/.well-known and 3) www.example.com .  The only one that works is #3.

Have also added the following intent filter to androidmanifest.xml and that does not work:

```
 <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <!-- Edit android:host to handle links to the target URL-->
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/app1" />
  </intent-filter>
```

I can't believe that you must have a different website for each progressive web app.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the documentation for the Progressive Web Apps stipulate?